# ASP:Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am trying to pass a value to a label from a data source, but it keeps on giving me this error.

form1.aspx:

```
 <asp:FormView ID="ProductsView" DataSourceID="ProductDataSource" DataKeyNames="Parking_ID"
                runat="server" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: solid 10px white; background-position: center;
                        background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url('<%# Eval("Parking_ID", "images/{0}.bmp") %>');">
                    </div>
                    <asp:HiddenField Value='<%# Eval("Parking_Cost") %>' ID="hiddenPrice" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField Value='<%# Eval("Parking_Name") %>' ID="hiddenName" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField Value='<%# Eval("Parking_ID") %>' ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:FormView>
             <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="TEST" CssClass="title" Style="font-size: 17px;
                display: block;"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text="TEST" CssClass="title" Style="color: Red;
                font-size: 12px;"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_ID" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="title" Style="color: Red;
                font-size: 12px;"></asp:Label>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ProductDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mydatabaseConnectionString2 %>"
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Parking] WHERE ([Parking_ID] = @Parking_ID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Parking_ID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

form1.aspx.vb:

```
lblName.Text = DirectCast(Me.ProductsView.FindControl("hiddenName"), HiddenField).Value
```

I am using vb.net script

Any ideas ?

Regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Controls are usually in the [data row of the FormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.row.aspx).

Try

```
lblName.Text = DirectCast(Me.ProductsView.Row.FindControl("hiddenName"), HiddenField).Value
```

But in general, when you use `Control.FindControl()`, there is a chance it will return `Nothing` if it cannot find it. So the best thing to do is do a `TryCast` instead of `DirectCast` and check to see if it's `Nothing`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the error source is the following statement:

```
Me.ProductsView.FindControl("hiddenName")
```

And the reason is that you dont have a `Control` with the `ID` of `"hiddenName"` **directly** in the `ProductsView` control.

You may need to use a *recursive function* to get the control ..

Answer (score 0):

Is this code in the bind event?

```
lblName.Text = DirectCast(Me.ProductsView.FindControl("hiddenName"), HiddenField).Value
```

If so, it might be that you have to check which template it is running:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ItemType || e.Item.ItemType == AlternateItemType)
```

<sup>(I'm not sure of the types for `FormView`, but in a `GridView` it would be like this.</sup>

The control `hiddenName` doesn't existing on other templates.

Also you have to find the control from `e.Item` which is the current template.